# Symfony: how to verify doctrine entities mapping consistency

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, mapping

Navigating my app built with Symfony I discovered some mappings of some entities are inconsistent.

The Symfony Profiler tells me this:

> AppBundle\Entity\Email     The mappings
> AppBundle\Entity\Email#forCustomer and
> AppBundle\Entity\Customer#emails are inconsistent with each other.

and, in reverse:

> AppBundle\Entity\Customer  The association
> AppBundle\Entity\Customer#emails refers to the owning side field
> AppBundle\Entity\Email#owner which does not exist.

**How can I check all entities in one time to discover this kind of inconsistency, without having to navigate all the app hoping I discover other inconsistencies?**

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For Symfony version **lower** than **3.4** you can try with:

`app/console doctrine:schema:validate`

and for Symfony **3.4**, **4.*** and **5.***:

`bin/console doctrine:schema:validate`

Comment: in some cases `bin/console`

Comment: I don't see differance